# linux kernel module prevent umount of filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems

I dont want user to umount a filesystem that is being monitored by my kernel module. How do I do that. I have pointer to the super_block and block_device available.

Only way I could do is open a dummy file in that partition and keep it open. Its ugly.

Comment: The filesystem has to be unmounted, at least when the system is shut down. You could have a user-land helper process using `inotify` ....

Comment: atomic_inc the vfsmount->mnt_count